# Find lock screen package in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, 19.04, lock-screen, bug-reporting

I want to report a bug in a lock screen. So i need to find a corresponding package.

According to this wiki 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingScreenLocking/HowScreenLockingWorks
this package should be called gnome-screensaver 
I tried to find an exact package name, but i could not. I have used following commands:

```
apt list --installed | grep screensaver
apt list --installed | grep gnome
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [link you provided](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingScreenLocking/HowScreenLockingWorks) is pretty old. `gnome-shell` uses `gdm3` instead of `gnome-screensaver` now.

try the following:

```
apt list gdm3
```

gives me:

```
Listing... Done
gdm3/disco,now 3.32.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
gdm3/disco 3.32.0-1ubuntu1 i386
```

As you can see, it says above that it is installed.

Comment: well that's much harder to interpret than the ouput for `apt list` in both installed and uninstalled cases isn't it?